# How to deployee windows phone 7 app using visual studio 2010 ultimate?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

could you please help me any one..., I had installed visual stdio 2010 ultimate but i couldn't find out where is XAPdeployee.exe tool located.

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio 2010 Express for windows Phone, which comes as part of the Windows Phone SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you installed the Windows Phone 7 SDK, which would be required for this procedure.

If you are just looking to run the tool it should be located at this path:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe.

There is a good guide located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512(v=vs.92).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you must install the SDK as it is not part of VS Ultimate.